# C# WebBrowser click method don't work when i publish web api to windows server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webbrowser-control, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an web api than make several searches and when i'm on developer enviroment (Windows 10 with VS 2017) the api works sucessfully, but when i publish de api on production enviroment (Win Server 2012 with .NET 4.6) the method of click button doesn't work.

My code:

```
  while (wb.Document.GetElementById("username") == null && DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds < 35000)
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }
                            wb.Document.GetElementById("username").InnerText = User;
                            wb.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = Pwd;
                            var button = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button").Cast<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("type") == "submit");
                            //if (button != null)
                            //    button.InvokeMember("click");

                            mshtml.HTMLButtonElement hie = (mshtml.HTMLButtonElement)button.DomElement;
                            hie.click();
                            step = 2;

                            HtmlElementCollection links = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
                            while (links.Count <= 3 && DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds < 35000)
                            {
                                links = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }
```

the method while (links.Count <= 3) enter on a infinite loop in server until elapsed 35 seconds of requisition start, because the links.count when click works have 17 items

[When click works, on dev enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKxrU.png)

Anyone knows a solution for my problem?

Thanks